# HashMap entry has been lost

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode, containskey

I don't understand why this code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Person, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        Person person = new Person("person");
        map.put(person, "");
        person.name = "person2";  // key's property changed
        System.out.println(map.containsKey(new Person("person")));
        System.out.println(map.containsKey(new Person("person2")));
    }

    static class Person {
        String name;

        Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Person person = (Person) o;
            return Objects.equals(name, person.name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(name);
        }

    }
}
```

prints `false` `false`. When I put `Person` object in a map, hash should be calculated. Then key's property is changed. While invoking `containsKey`, hashes should be compared and `new Person("person2")` has the same hash as previously inserted key. What happens that in both cases `containsKey` evaluates to false?

Comment: Why use `Objects.hash(name)` instead of `name.hashCode()`?

Comment: And HashMaps don't expect key hashcodes to change, I don't think there's anything in place to update which bucket it's stored in _(using the API in an undefined way may result in undefined behaviour)_

Comment: Or why not just make the hashmap take in String keys and pass the name as the key?

Comment: @phflack Is there a difference in that? Does it matter?

Comment: @user7 No, it's just unnecessary complexity, which can hinder debugging

Comment: you cannot mutate the properties that are part of hashcode generation

Comment: `Objects.hash(name)` invokes internally `name.hashCode()` so that should not be the case. I know that mutating properties of a key is not good idea, but I don't understand internal implementation...

Comment: I was in the middle of writing an answer when this was closed, but mutating a `Person` that has already been set as a key to the `Map` **does not** change the bucket that it has been inserted in.  However, it **does** change the object's `hashCode`.  Because of this, checking if the `Map` contains `new Person("person")` gets close to finding the object (it begins to check the same bucket that the object is located in), but the `hashCode`s differ, so it returns `false`.

Comment: @Orch I didn't pass the `String` because it's immutable so this problem wouldn't happen

Comment: @JacobG. When we call for `new Person("person")` it gets to the right bucket - do u mean it returns false, because it is no longer `equal`? (`person` != `person2`)`?

Comment: @user7 I'd post the source code for `Map#getNode`  here if I could, but yes, you're correct!  Take OP's code and always return `true` in `Person#equals`, and then `map.containsKey(new Person("person"))` returns `true`.

Comment: @JacobG. So the hashcodes differing does not play any role for `person` string as it got to the correct bucket somehow and everything from here on is only `equals`

Comment: @user7 When `new Person("person")` was added to the `Map`, it was put in some bucket `X`.  Changing the object's `name` to `"person2"` does **not** move it from bucket `X` into another bucket.  Therefore, checking `map.containsKey(new Person("person"))` navigates to bucket `X`, and then checks `equals` on all objects within the bucket, returning `"person2".equals("person")`: `false`

Comment: @JacobG. Clear. That's what I actually meant btw. Thanks

Comment: @JacobG. thanks for explanation.